# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.codename1.ui.Label cannot be cast to com.codename1.components.MultiButton

Tags: java, codenameone

i have been doing [the SearchToolBar CodeNameOne API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html) and ran into CLassCastException

```
for(Component cmp : f.getContentPane()) {
        MultiButton mb = (MultiButton)cmp;
        String line1 = mb.getTextLine1();
        String line2 = mb.getTextLine2();
        boolean show = line1 != null && line1.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1 ||
                line2 != null && line2.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
        mb.setHidden(!show);
        mb.setVisible(show);
    }
```

the output pointed the error on this line :

**MultiButton mb = (MultiButton)cmp;**

Comment: Please put the error message in the question.

Comment: Also since we don't know what `f` is and what its content is we can't really help you. Also imo the error message says all you need to know, to know what the problem is. `f` contains an object of type `com.codename1.ui.Label` but you want to cast is to the type `com.codename1.components.MultiButton` which is not a super class of the other type.

Comment: @Ackdari the error msg is the title of this question , as for  f it's a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is actually in the preceding code and not in the code you have submitted here. The code you have provided here (pulled from the link you also provided) assumes that `f.getContentPane()` only contains `MultiButton` and no other type of `Component`.

In the example you have linked, the creator is iterating through components, casting each one to a `MultiButton`. In order for this cast to succeed, the object that is assigned to `cmp` in each iteration of the loop has to actually be a `MultiButton`.

In your code, while iterating in your for-loop, at one point cmp is assigned a value of type `com.codename1.ui.Label`, this type is not a `MultiButton` so the cast fails and throws the runtime exception `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

To fix: either ensure that the `ContentPane` only contains `MultiButton`s or add a check inside your for loop to skip an iteration if the component isn't a `MultiButton` like follows:

```
for(Component cmp : f.getContentPane()) {
    if(cmp instanceof MultiButton) {
        // your original for-loop body here
    }
}
```

Comment: it solved the error , yet if figured the search isn't working at all like nothing happens when i type in it , any further help ?

Comment: This isn't really the forum for "general tutoring" or "help me debug my program" type questions (I learned this the hard way myself), this is only really for asking specific questions.